# Converting Networkx graph to data frame with its attributes

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I had two graphs, g1 and g2. I have applied some rules and mapped them as shown below.

graph:

[image]

I would like to convert back the mapped graph to the pandas data frame /table/.

```
From        Attribute        To         
10/10       Start          130/21
130/21      Left           190/190
190/190     Right          240/204
240/204     End             -
```

Is there any way to do this in Python Pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def make_node_df(G):
    nodes = {}
    for node, attribute in G.nodes(data=True):
        if not nodes.get('node'):
            nodes['node'] = [node]
        else:
            nodes['node'].append(node)

        for key, value in attribute.items():
            if not nodes.get(key):
                nodes[key] = [value]
            else:
                nodes[key].append(value)

    return pd.DataFrame(nodes)

def make_edge_df(G):
    edges = {}
    for source, target, attribute in G.edges(data=True):

        if not edges.get('source'):
            edges['source'] = [source]
        else:
            edges['source'].append(source)

        if not edges.get('target'):
            edges['target'] = [target]
        else:
            edges['target'].append(target)

        for key, value in attribute.items():
            if not edges.get(key):
                edges[key] = [value]
            else:
                edges[key].append(value)
    return pd.DataFrame(edges)


def node_df_to_ebunch(df, nodename='node'):

    attributes = [col for col in df.columns if not col==nodename]

    ebunch = []

    for ix, row in df.iterrows():
        ebunch.append((row[nodename], {attribute:row[attribute] for attribute in attributes}))

    return ebunch
```

So, you can convert the nodes of the Graph to a dataframe with make_node_df, and the edges with make_edge_df.

If you want to go from a dataframe to a graph, you can use the inbuilt function nx.from_pandas_edgelist with the edge dataframe, and for the nodes, you can do:

```
G = nx.Graph()
nodes = node_df_to_ebunch(df, nodename='node')
G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
```

Comment: I can get the ```From``` and ```To``` but got error to get the ```Attribute```. ```KeyError: 'Attribute' ```.

Comment: @Kapital That means the edge attribute is not stored under that name. Can you try to type print(G.edges(data=True)) ? This will give you an idea about which keys are used

Comment: I can see it when ```print(G.node(data=True))``` but not ```print(G.edges(data=True))```.

Comment: Is there a way to add that attribute to edge information as well?

Comment: sure, but this would introduce ambiguity: if both nodes connected by one edge have different attributes, which one would you pick for the edge?

Comment: Indeed. I would prefer to get the attribute from node information instead of the edges.

Comment: I have sent you a message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215995/discussion-between-kapital-and-warped).